# Pandas groupby and subtract rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
id variable year value
1      a    2020   2
1      a    2021   3
1      a    2022   5
1      b    2020   3
1      b    2021   8
1      b    2022   10
```

I want to groupby id and variable and subtract 2020 values from all the rows of the group. So I will get:

```
id variable year value
1      a    2020   0
1      a    2021   1
1      a    2022   3
1      b    2020   0
1      b    2021   5
1      b    2022   7
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Some problem with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Although `2020` is not the first of group we could use**: [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
df['value']= df['value'].sub(df['value'].where(df['year'].eq(2020))
                                        .groupby([df['id'],df['variable']])
                                        .transform('max'))
print(df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020    0.0
1   1        a  2021    1.0
2   1        a  2022    3.0
3   1        b  2020    0.0
4   1        b  2021    5.0
5   1        b  2022    7.0
```

---

if **year** it is `string`you could need

```
df['year'].eq('2020')
```

Comment: We need to make sure, values are sorted first with column `year`, right?

Comment: not here because transform `max` omits the NaN values, which have been created with `series.where` @Celius Stingher

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) if not sure if `2020` is first per groups:

```
df1 = df[df['year'].eq(2020)]
df['value'] -= df.merge(df1,how='left',on=['id','variable'],suffixes=('_',''))['value'].values
print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      0
1   1        a  2021      1
2   1        a  2022      3
3   1        b  2020      0
4   1        b  2021      5
5   1        b  2022      7
```

If `2020` is always first per groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['value'] -= df.groupby(['id','variable'])['value'].transform('first')
print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      0
1   1        a  2021      1
2   1        a  2022      3
3   1        b  2020      0
4   1        b  2021      5
5   1        b  2022      7
```

EDIT:

If in data are duplicated `2020` rows per groups solution first remove dupes and subtract only first value:

```
print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      3
1   1        a  2020      2
2   1        a  2022      5
3   1        b  2020      3
4   1        b  2021      8
5   1        b  2022     10

df1 = df[df['year'].eq(2020)]
df['value'] -= df.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(['id','variable']),
                        how='left',
                        on=['id','variable'],
                        suffixes=('_',''))['value'].values

print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      0
1   1        a  2020     -1
2   1        a  2022      2
3   1        b  2020      0
4   1        b  2021      5
5   1        b  2022      7
```

Or aggregate values, e.g. by `sum` for deduplicate data:

```
print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      3
1   1        a  2020      1
2   1        a  2022      5
3   1        b  2020      3
4   1        b  2021      8
5   1        b  2022     10

df = df.groupby(['id','variable','year'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      4
1   1        a  2022      5
2   1        b  2020      3
3   1        b  2021      8
4   1        b  2022     10

df1 = df[df['year'].eq(2020)]
df['value'] -= df.merge(df1, how='left',
                        on=['id','variable'],
                        suffixes=('_',''))['value'].values

print (df)
   id variable  year  value
0   1        a  2020      0
1   1        a  2022      1
2   1        b  2020      0
3   1        b  2021      5
4   1        b  2022      7
```

Comment: merge here is totally unnecessary and slower

Comment: @ansev - OK, please add some timings for prove it, I think `merge` is faster like `groupby`

Comment: `Merge` is much more slow than `Series.where`. trivial

Comment: @ansev - You forget for `.groupby([df['id'],df['variable']])
                                        .transform('max')` ?

Comment: `groupby.transform` is faster than `merge` you also are creating `df1`

Comment: @ansev - hmmm, I trust you if create some serious timings with some 10, 100, 1000 unique groups. From my experience `groupby` is really slow.

Comment: I tried this, but some 2020 values aren't becoming 0

Comment: @jezrael Now I am getting this error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16152240,) (16163760,)`

Comment: @Ank - Problem is duplicates `2020` rows, solution is `df1 = df[df['year'].eq(2020)]`
`df['value'] -= df.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(['id','variable']),how='left',on=['id','variable'],suffixes=('_',''))['value'].values`

Comment: @Ank - It create negative values, not sure if it is expected, edited answer for see it.